# Latest and stable version of kurento

Tags: kurento

What is the latest and stable version of `Kurento media server` as if we visit [kurento.org](http://kurento.org) in the documentations pages somewhere it is mention kurento v6.1.1 somewhere it is kurento v6.4.0. This you can see in these screen shots

[image]

[image]

In the documentation there are versions mentioned kurento v6.1.1, v6.0.0, v.5.1.0 but if I'm opening installation guide of v6.1.1 it is giving all commands to install kurento v6.0.0.

```
'echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

So what is the newest stable version of kurento media server and how to install it? If kurento v6.1.1 is released then how to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Kurento, at the time of this post, is 6.4.0. You cand find it the [official project's documentation page](http://www.kurento.org/documentation) in several formats. Not sure where you found those references to 6.1.1, unless you were following an outdated link to the documentation.

If you find outdated links, please open a bug in our [bugtracker](https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker) project.

---

EDIT 1

You shouldn't be finding this issue again. Now, all outdated links are pointing to the new documentation location.

Comment: How to install newest version of Kurento media server?? If installation with the same commands metioned above in the question can I know which version do I have is there any command to know it?

Comment: @AkshayRathore That command always installs the latest version. If you do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, you'll get the latest version. Finding the version can be done reading the server logs, or executing `dpkg -l | grep kms`. That will tell you the exact version of all Kurento packages and modules.

Comment: @AkshayRathore We've solved the issue by redirecting all the outdated doc links to the new documentation location. Don't forget to accept if valid ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Latest release is 6.4.0, there seems to be problems on the documentation release process and this is why there are references to other versions. Please, report all the reference to previous versions so we can fix them. You can use [this](https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker) bugtracker to repor

Answer (score -1):

The new version of the kurento is released.

http://www.kurento.org/blog/kurento-67-moving-forward

Comment: @JackFlamp the question asks for it. Close the question